# Faulty output on save vector layer as (export/save features as) / PostgreSQL SQL dump

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, export

i just did an export of a PostGIS-db polygon dataset via "/export/save feature as" using the PostgreSQL SQL dump option taking standard settings - which seemed to be correct for the existing field-types.
The resulting SQL file turned out to be incorrect and the editor app showed the following:

[image]

while I would have expected something like this (which was done by DBeaver export using the database dump function) :
[image]

The first image shows, that the type definition of the columns is ok, while the insert into statements do repeate the column names instead of inserting the existing values.
Are there any options in the QGIS export dialog to be set in order to get valid results?

Comment: Explicitly defining columns on `INSERT` is standard SQL; do the actual values not appear after that list as `VALUES` tuples?

Comment: The answer is - they do. While running slightly outdated, yet valid commands, QGIS also honors the geometry column registration, as well as adding a proper `SERIAL` + `PRIMARY KEY CONSTRAINT` and a spatial index. You can change the PK column to your existing `id` if you wish.

Comment: Interesting. It seems the export engine reaches STDOUT line length limtis or something similar, so the lines are truncated. That's unfortunate.

Comment: @geozelot - sublime editor was not able to manage the sql.dump. so I couldn't check the data to verify your assumption. and it took a while to check that the numeric data of course is existing but somewhere on the far right because of the leading geom column of the qgis-dump. think i have to work on my standard SQL skills. but anyway reimport doesn't work. ... line length limits would be inconvenient since the geometry information determines the amount of data ..

Comment: just a remark: the INSERT INTO statements seems to be ok from a formal point of view. each of them ends with ); ... so, does the STDOUT problem just affect the output of the geom-coloumn  and truncates the binary information inside while writing to the output ?